Roblox studio scripting
I watched a tutorial on how to make a tower defense game(from gnomecode),I need help,I stopped at 6# video on how to make tower placement, but when I finished making the script and checked everything seemed fine, but when I clicked on tower name GUI button it started to spam errors in output like

Players.Playername.PlayerGui.GameGui.GameController:96: attempt to index nil with 'Size'

Here is the game controller script(The render part(96 line is local y)
RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if towerToSpawn then
        local result = MouseRaycast({towerToSpawn})
        if result and result.Instance then
            if result.Instance.Parent.Name == "TowerArea" then
                canPlace = true
                ColorPlaceholderTower(Color3.new(0,1,0))
            else
                canPlace = false
                ColorPlaceholderTower(Color3.new(1,0,0))
            end
            local x = result.Position.X
            local y = result.Position.Y + towerToSpawn.Humanoid.HipHeight + (towerToSpawn.PrimaryPart.Size.Y * 2)
            local z = result.Position.Z

            local cframe = CFrame.new(x,y,z) * CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(rotation), 0)
            towerToSpawn:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(cframe)
        end
    end
end)

I tried to use chatgpt but it only helped to stop error ut after that tower model didn't even didn't show up.

Try using CFrame instead
CFrame Docs
